# working with mysql database

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I'm writing a shell script to fetch the table from a mysql database (part of database actually, from a particular time period to another) and put that into .csv file.
Here's what I have written,and I'm getting an error

```
mysql -u -p -B -e "use mytable;select * from table3;" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > filename.csv
```

(multiple queries of mysql)

(please also hint as to how can I extract the data from the mysql table for a particular time period,say Jan 23 16:05 to Jan 30 17:05)

Please note that table3 is to come from a shell variable newtable
so I have to use $newtable in the code
And I have to use shell only

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: please edit your question and copy/paste the exact errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use newtable in your script:

```
newtable="table3"
"mysql -u -p -B -e "use mytable;select * from $newtable;"
```

For query part assuming you are using "date type" column say with the name "period" then query would be:

```
"Select * from table3 where MONTHNAME(period)='January';
```

Check this latest update as per your requirement:

```
 date="2010-08-11"
 start="10:09:09"
 end="21:50:59"

"Select * from table3 where DATE(period)='$date' and TIME(period) between  
'$start'and '$end'";
```

Comment: Hi all,
the errors have all been resolved.kudos.
the problem that I'm still geting is that I'm unable to generate the database for a particular time period for someday. The date,starting time and the end time are returned by shell variables
say eg

date="2013-08-07"
start="01:30:00"
end="02:00:00"

so how do I get the database made on $date between the times $start and $end

thanks

Comment: what is the field data type and the field name which keeps your date/time record in your table.

Comment: for date,it is IVALDATE
for start time it is IVALSTART

Answer (score 0):

If you can query into a csv file with mysql:

echo "SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM $newtable;" | mysql -u -p -B mytable

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html